# Can I stop postgres running in the background?

Tags: postgresql

On Kubuntu 20.04

Before I can successfully start a docker container on my computer I need to kill a Postgres process. I do this by:

1. `sudo ss -lptn 'sport = :5432'`

,which outputs:
`State   Recv-Q  Send-Q    Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port  Process   LISTEN  0       244           127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*      users:(("postgres",pid=1003,fd=5))`

2. `kill <pid>`

Now I would be able to run the docker container that has a Postgres database.
I'd like it so that I don't have to follow those steps before I can run any Postgres database.
For some reason `lsof -i :5432` does not return the process.

Is it standard behaviour for Postgres to be running in the background?
Is it safe to stop this process?
If yes, how can I stop this process from running automatically in the background?

I have tried the following commands with no success:

`sudo systemctl disable postgresql`

`sudo update-rc.d postgresql disable`

Comment: If the Postgres process is associated PostgreSQL then this article may help you.  https://fatdragon.me/blog/2016/05/managing-postgresql-process-ubuntu-service-pgctl-and-pgctlcluster  If you don't have PostgreSQL installed, then you need to 1. find out what the process is and what it does.  Then decide if you need it running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Killing a database process is a really good way of destroying a database. PostgreSQL is not installed by default so *something or someone* must have put it on the machine for a reason. You will want to confirm if anything on your system needs it.

To answer the question, though, you can safely stop PostgreSQL like this:

```
sudo service postgresql stop
```

You can prevent PostgreSQL from starting at boot like this:

```
sudo service postgresql disable
```

If nothing on your system needs the database engine to be installed locally, you can remove it:

```
sudo apt --purge remove postgresql
```

<sup>**Note:** This removes just the server element, leaving the client libraries intact to connect to PostgreSQL installations.</sup>

Comment: thanks for your comment but `sudo service postgresql disable` doesn't do anything. It returns `sudo service postgresql disable`

Comment: Have also tried `sudo systemctl disable postgresql`, but that didn't fix it

Comment: and tried `sudo update-rc.d postgresql disable`